# CSS :first-child pseudo-class simple example not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

As far as I can tell, this simple example below should be working but it doesn't. I'm obviously missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

The first `.field` div should have red text, but it simply does not...

Running Chrome browser on Mac.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obbmjd

```css
p .field:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div class="field">first - should be red</div>
  <div class="field">second</div>
</p>
```

Comment: This is because you can't put a div in a p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML is invalid.

A `p` element can't contain a `div` element. This results in the following:

```
<p></p>
  <div class="field">first - should be red</div>
  <div class="field">second</div>
<p></p>
```

As you can see, the browser is automatically closing the `p` tags, which explains why your selector isn't matching anything.

---

If the HTML was actually valid, then your selector would work. For instance, if you replace the `div` elements with `span` elements, the following would work:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nxxodq)

```
p .field:first-child {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!  That explains what's going on.  Will accept this as answer once timer allows.

Comment: @DanL See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element for a list of what elements a `<p>` can contain, and to read about flow content vs phrasing content.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.field:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I've tried `.field:first-child` as well and it also does not work.